# Find the Kth smallest element in a matrix of sorted rows

Tags: java, algorithm, heap

This is an interview question.

Find the Kth smallest element in a matrix of sorted rows, but NOT sorted columns and no relations between the rows. (the first row and nth row have no relation between them - all that is known is that each row is in ascending order)

An example input is this:

```
[[1,50,60],
 [20,30,40],
 [2,3,4]]
k = 5
```

And the output in this scenario would be

```
20
```

because 20 is the 5th smallest element in this matrix.

I first thought of adding all the elements to a minHeap, then polling the elements while subtracting one from k each iteration until we have our answer. I also thought about implementing quickselect for a O(m*n) solution, although these solutions dont really take advantage of the fact that all the rows are sorted in ascending order.

What is the optimal way to solve this problem? After thinking about it, I realize it seems like a 'merge k sorted lists' question, where we stop after we find the kth smallest element.

Thanks

Comment: _"sorted rows, but NOT sorted columns and no relations between the rows"_. Can you add sample input/output? How can rows be sorted in an ascending order if there is no relation between the rows?

Comment: Added. What I mean by no relation between the rows is the rows are in ascending order, but the second row has nothing to do with the first, and nothing to do with the third, fourth, or nth row.

Comment: Are you familiar with merge sort?

Comment: If all items are positive integers and if they all of them are unique as shown in the example then you can perhaps come up with something better than merge sort.

Answer (score 5):

Assume the following case

```
[[1,3,4,...10],
[1,3,4,...10],
[1,2,4,...10]]
For k = 4, ans = 2
```

Since each row has the same starting/ending element and there's no relation between any two rows, it's hard to determine any useful information without using some brute forcing. The simplest solution should be

1. Have a max heap with the first `k` elements of the matrix
2. Start traversing the remaining elements/rows. If current element is less than `max_heap.top`, pop the heap and add the current value to it. Else, stop the iteration for the current row (since we can't have the `kth` smallest element here)

This has minor improvements over complete bruteforcing, but still has `O(m*n)` time and `O(k)` space complexity.

Edit:
You can sort the matrix rows based on their first element (break ties using the last element) in `O(mlog(m))` time to reduce the number of heap push/pop operations. (For a monotonically decreasing matrix, you'll be pushing/popping a heap element at each case, which would degrade performance.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What if there aren't K elements per row? For the example K = 15 and each row only has 5 elements? Also, I thought adding and removing elements from a heap was log(n), so how would this be O(m*n)? But quickselect would be O(m*n) in the average case, right?

Comment: @s_jack_frost why would it matter if there are `K` elements in a row or not? We have one heap for all rows, not one heap per row

Comment: If rows are short, then add elements until the heap is full, which may mean using more then one row.

Comment: @rossum correct, clarified that in the answer

Comment: This is a very interesting method indeed! I think that the worst case will be when you fill the entire heap at each line. in that cast since heapify takes `O(log(k))` the runtime will be `O(n*k*log(k))` when `n`  is the number of rows. If `k=m` the number of columns this is the absolute worst case and the runtime will be `O(n*m*log(m))`

Comment: @TomerGeva very specific case, but good point. Edited the answer to work around that problem

Comment: I think Tomer's comment still applies and the algorithm is still potentially `O(n*m log (mn))`, unless I'm not understanding your edit. How does having the rows sorted by first element avoid the problem they mention?

Comment: @kcsquared you'll fill the heap each time only if all elements in the current row are smaller than the previous row's elements. By sorting in a non-decreasing order, that can be avoided

Comment: After sorting the rows by the first element, the worst case will be filling the heap `k-1` times in each row, this still means that the worst case runtime is `O(n*m*log(m))`

Comment: Pick some value of `n` (say, n=10) and look at the matrix you get from the Python line `matrix = [[-i] + list(range(i*n, (i+1)*n)) for i in range(n)][::-1]` . The matrix has rows already sorted by first element, and if you let `k = n*n/2`, I think the current algorithm here has `O(n*m log (mn))` runtime for a matrix like that

Answer (score 4):

One approach that does take advantage of the sorted rows is nested binary search, which is faster when the range of values isn't too large. If your matrix has `m` rows and `n` columns, and some `Range` equal to `max(Matrix)-min(Matrix)+1`, the time complexity can be written as

`O(m * (log n) * (log Range))`

The idea behind the algorithm is just the definition of `kth` smallest element as

- "The value such that `k-1` elements of the matrix are smaller than the value."

In a matrix, this becomes

- "The value such that the sum over each row of the matrix of (the number of elements smaller than value) is equal to `k-1`".

In a single row, we can count how many elements are smaller than some `x` using binary search in `log n` time. For the whole matrix, this takes `m * log n` time. Initially, you should scan the first and last columns of the matrix to find the smallest and largest values in the matrix, respectively, for your outer binary search bounds.

---

Here's the pseudocode for the rest of the algorithm:

1. Scan the first column of matrix and find the minimum; call this `low`
2. Scan the last column of matrix and find the maximum; call this `high`
3. While `low < high`:

   - Let `mid = (low + high)/2`
   - Count the number of elements smaller than `mid` in the matrix, using binary search

     - If this count is less than `k-1`: Set `low = mid + 1`
     - Else: Set `high = mid`
4. Return `low`

Comment: I thought there were `n` rows and not `m`. Retracted the point

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Got it; I realize that my notation is flipped from the other answer.

Comment: Use the *k*th column in step 2.

Comment: @greybeard Thanks; that's probably faster, but I can't find a neat way to write the complexity of the resulting algorithm. If `k` is small compared to `m*n`, then a solution like Tomer's that runs in `O(num_rows + k * (log num_rows))` is probably faster, anyways

Answer (score 2):

The key to the solution is that **all the rows are sorted**. I will suggest the following:

Given a row-ordered matrix `A`:

1. Init a min heap with tuples of `0`th index value of each row and their corresponding row numbers as `min_heap` where the location in the heap is defined by the value and the row number is for time optimization.
2. Init an `index_vec = zeros([1, n])` to be the lngth equal to the number of rows where all the values in the vector are `0` since the starting index is `0` (`n` is the number of rows)
3. pop the top of `min_heap`and push into `min_value_tuple`
4. Advance `index_vec[min_value_tuple[1]] += 1`
5. push `A[chosen_row, index_vec[min_value_tuple[1]]]` into the min heap as a tuple with the corresponding row number.
6. return to step 3. for K times
7. pop the top of `min_heap` and return it

**Note** if during the loop in steps 3. through 6. `index_vec[ii] = m` where m is the number of colums, we will not push a new number to `min_heap` and just orgenize the heap to accomodate a new root.

### Time complexity

1. Building the initial heaps takes O(n) since there are `n` numbers in the heap
2. K iteration of pushing numbers into the heap is O(klog(n))

Total runtime will be O(n + klong(n)).

Worst case is for `k=m*n/2`. In that case the time complexity will be O(n + nmlog(n)) = O(nmlog(n)).

### Space

This requires a heap with size `n` and `index_vec` with size `n` as well so total space is O(n)

### Note

If `k > n*m/2` you can solve an equivalent problem if finding the `n*m-k` largest number in the matrix after flipping the rows of `A`.

Comment: Initialise the min heap from step 1 with *k* / *m* elements from each row: heapify is linear, insert superlinear.

Comment: This is a great solution, but why do you need two heaps/ the shadow heap at all? The algorithm seems simpler to describe if you have a single heap of (value, row_index) pairs

Comment: @kcsquared Thank you sir, it is better to explain that way, edited that in

Answer (score 2):

Sort the matrix by row, followed by iterating over the row element `k` times.

```
Time complexity: (n + k) log n
Space complexity: n * m
n = number of rows
m = number of columns
```

```
public class KthSmallestElementMatrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int[][] matrix = {
          {1, 50, 60},
          {20, 30, 40},
          {2, 3, 4}
        };
        int k = 5;

        System.out.println(kthSmallestElement(matrix, k));
    }

    static class ArrayElement implements Comparable<ArrayElement> {

        int[] arr;

        int index;

        ArrayElement(int[] arr) {
            this.arr = arr;
            this.index = 0;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < arr.length;
        }

        public int next() {

            if (hasNext()) {
                return arr[index++];
            } else {
                return arr[index];
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(ArrayElement o) {
            return Integer.compare(this.arr[index % arr.length], o.arr[o.index % arr.length]);
        }
    }

    private static int kthSmallestElement(int[][] matrix, int k) throws Exception {

        Queue<ArrayElement> q = new PriorityQueue<ArrayElement>();

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            q.add(new ArrayElement(matrix[i]));
        }

        int element = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            ArrayElement ae = q.poll();

            element = ae.next();

            if (ae.hasNext()) {
                q.add(ae);
            }
        }

        return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be more helpful to add an explanation for your algorithm

Comment: You have a mismatched brace in your time complexity formula. Also, shouldn't it be `(n + k) log n`? After all, adding to a queue costs `log n` every time.

Comment: you are right @meriton the time complexity is `(n + k) log n`; `n log n + k log n = (n + k) log n`

Answer (score 1):

Lets define a min-heap that stores a pair of values, then the algorithm consists of the following steps:

1- iterate through the values of the first column of the matrix and add each value to the heap as a pair of (value, row index).

2- repeat the following step exactly k-1 times: store the row index of the top pair of the heap in idx, then delete this pair. Now go to the row with index equal to idx and add the next unused element in it to the heap in the same way as before. After k-1 iterations the top element would contain the K-th element.

The time complexity of the first step is O(n.log n) such that n is the number of rows of the matrix. The time comexity of the second step is O(k.log n) because we will delet/add k-1 elements from/to the heap and at each moment the heap contains no more than n elements. So the total time complexity is O((n+k)log n).

Comment: In the worst case, it becomes `O(mn*log(n))`

Comment: Yeah when k = n*m

Comment: @AbhinavMathur No, the time complexity is not dependent on the number of elements in the row. The row can grow unbounded without changing the running time of the algorithm. The fact that k can grow to a maximum size of m*n is irrelevant.

Comment: @beaker _"The fact that k can grow to a maximum size of m*n is irrelevant"_. How is that irrelevant while analysing the worst case?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Because of the previous two sentences in my comment.

Comment: @beaker so `O((n+k)log n)` will not evaluate to `O(mn*log n)` when `k=mn`?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur no. Not when you put that `O` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Run quickselect on the first *k* elements of each row for O(*kn*) time.

Comment: What if `k` is greater than the number of columns?